# Jar files in ASP.NET website

Tags: asp.net, jar

I have the following:

1. ASP.NET website using the 3.5 framework
2. One folder that contains a jar and a cab file of a control that I need to use on some of my webpages. The control is used to render maps.

What is the best way to use this control on my website? I know there are the object and applet tags, but I'm very unfamiliar with both. This project was dumped on me, and quite frankly, it's not in my area of expertise, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You may take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/651032/classnotfoundexception-in-java-applet-using-object-tag

Comment: Thank you! The link you supplied was helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used a Java applet on an ASP.NET page with the `applet` tag, but I was downloading the code (is that the .jar file?) from another site so this may/may not help but here's how mine is broadly set up:

`<applet`  start off with an applet tag  with the following as attributes
`archive=""` - I *think* this is where you'd put the path to the .cab file
`codebase=""` - I *think* this is the path to the .jar file
`code=""` - I *think* this tells the JVM which class to extract from the archive/codebase and run
`height="350"` and `width="500"` - self-explanatory
`viewastext=""` - honestly, I have no idea what this does.
then close the tag `>`
I've then got a set of self-closing `param` tags, including ones for codebase, archive and code which repeat what's in the applet tag e.g.

```
<param name="codebase" value="" />
```

and then a closing `</applet>` tag.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I ended up using the applet tag. What I discovered is that the w3c says the applet tag is deprecated, but that Sun still recommends using it.