# Separate Objects for IE and FF

Tags: html, object, applet

I'm trying to embed my java applet using the object tag in html. While trying to research how to accomplish this task I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/651032/classnotfoundexception-in-java-applet-using-object-tag) SO post.

when trying to put the code into action on my page it looks a little something like this...

```
<object name="Battleship"
    width="750" 
    height="800"
    classid="java:ApplicationApplet.class"
    type="application/x-java-applet">
    <object classid="clsid:8AD9C840-044E-11D1-B3E9-00805F499D93"
        codebase="http://java.sun.com/update/1.5.0/jinstall-1_5_0-windows-i586.cab"
        height="800"
        width="750">
        <param name="code" value="ApplicationApplet" />
        Your browser is not Java enabled.
     </object>
</object>
```

However, when I run this it crashes IE, but is fine in FF. I'm curious if there's something I'm missing to distinguish that IE should run the inner object and FF and others the outer object?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the conditional comments

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_comment

```
<!--[if !IE]> Firefox and others will use outer object -->
<object name="Battleship"
    width="750" 
    height="800"
    classid="java:ApplicationApplet.class"
    type="application/x-java-applet">
    <!--<![endif]-->
    <!-- MSIE (Microsoft Internet Explorer) will use inner object --> 
    <object classid="clsid:8AD9C840-044E-11D1-B3E9-00805F499D93"
        codebase="http://java.sun.com/update/1.5.0/jinstall-1_5_0-windows-i586.cab"
        height="800"
        width="750">
        <param name="code" value="ApplicationApplet" />
        Your browser is not Java enabled.
     </object>
<!--[if !IE]> close outer object -->
  </object>
  <!--<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Ahh... I had a feeling those were more than just comments, but didn't know what they were called so couldn't research them.