# Java Applet "ClassNotFoundException" on Firefox 52.4.1 - works on IE

Tags: java, ssl, firefox, applet, pkcs#11

We need to run an old web application which using Java 8 Applet (sick), on Firefox 52.4.1 (last version compatible with Java Applet) and Internet Explorer 11.

The applet is based on Java 8 and distributed by an Apache Tomcat server.
It is signed and obfuscated (Proguard).

The user connect to the website with SSL mutual authentication from a smartcard (The client needs a PKCS11 module to get the certificate from the smartcard).
The SSL mutual authentication is also done with the Java Applet.

All certificates are signed by an autority added in every browsers, windows and Java certificates stores.

Here the HTML code:

```html
<object classid='clsid:8AD9C840-044E-11D1-B3E9-00805F499D93' id='AsapiObject'>
    <param name='archive' value='../../../applet/myapplet.jar'/>
    <param name='code' value='main.package.Main'/>
    <param name='name' value='My Applet'/>
    <param name='mayscript' value='true'/>
    <comment>
        <applet id='AsapiApplet'
                name='My Applet'
                archive='../../../applet/myapplet.jar'
                code='main.package.Main'
                MAYSCRIPT="MAYSCRIPT">
        </applet>
    </comment>
</object>
```

(Followed recommandations from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/applet/using_tags.html#applet)

It works fine on IE 11, not on Mozilla Firefox 52.4.1.
Its the same JRE on both.

On Mozilla Firefox 52.4.1, I have a Java exception :

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: main.package.Main
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.initAppletAdapter(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

And before this exception, I have an `handshake failure exception` :

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:2023)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1125)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:153)
    at sun.plugin.PluginURLJarFileCallBack.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin.PluginURLJarFileCallBack.retrieve(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.retrieve(URLJarFile.java:205)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(URLJarFile.java:71)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(JarFileFactory.java:109)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(JarURLConnection.java:122)
    at sun.plugin.net.protocol.jar.CachedJarURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin.net.protocol.jar.CachedJarURLConnection.getJarFileInternal(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin.net.protocol.jar.CachedJarURLConnection.getJarFile(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.getJarFile(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.access$800(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.ensureOpen(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath.getLoader(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath.getLoader(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath.getResource(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.findClassHelper(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.initAppletAdapter(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I think Firefox doesn't import properly client certificate from the smartcard.

*Edit : there is also two other interesting lines in Java console :*

```
security: Accessing keys and certificate in Mozilla user profile: null
security: JSS is not configured
```

By increasing debug mode (`-Djavax.net.debug=all`), I see :

- **Internet Explorer :**

  ```
  *** ServerHelloDone

  [read] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 4
  0000: 0E 00 00 00                                        ....
  ssl: KeyMgr: getting aliases: [XXXXXXX (verified: OK), YYYYYYYYYYYYYY]
  ssl: Ignoring alias XXXXXXX (1): key algorithm does not match
  ssl: Ignoring alias XXXXXXX: key algorithm does not match
  ssl: Ignoring alias XXXXXXX (2): key algorithm does not match
  ssl: KeyMgr: no matching alias found
  ssl: Ignoring alias XXXXXXX (1): key algorithm does not match
  ssl: Ignoring alias XXXXXXX: key algorithm does not match
  ssl: Ignoring alias XXXXXXX (2): key algorithm does not match
  ssl: KeyMgr: no matching alias found
  *** Certificate chain
  chain [0] = [
  ...
  ```
- **Mozilla Firefox :**

  ```
  *** ServerHelloDone
  [read] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 4
  0000: 0E 00 00 00                                        ....
  Warning: no suitable certificate found - continuing without client authentication
  *** Certificate chain
  <Empty>
  ***
  ```

I tried/checked a lot of things :

- Checking if IAS_PKCS11 module is correctly installed on Firefox :

[image: Firefox PKCS11 module]

- Tried to disable`plugins.click_to_play` (https://support.mozilla.org/fr/questions/933135)
- Checked parameters order in `<applet>` ([ClassNotFoundException in Java Applet using <object> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/651032/classnotfoundexception-in-java-applet-using-object-tag))
- Cleared cache, added JRE arguments, JRE reinstallation ... (https://support.mozilla.org/fr/questions/945083)
- Enabled `security.enterprise_roots.enabled` (https://support.umbrella.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000669728-Configuring-Firefox-to-use-the-Windows-Certificate-Store)
- Used `<embed>` or  `<object>` instead of  `<applet>`.
- Tried a lot every combination in Advanced Security Parameter in Java Configuration
- Disabled some Security Checks (CRL, etc.).
- **Edit** : according to [JDK-6975851](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6975851), [JSS doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/NSS/JSS), [NSS versions](https://wiki.mozilla.org/NSS:Versions), I have built [JSS_4_4_20170313](https://hg.mozilla.org/projects/jss/file/055aa3ce8a61) based on [NSS 3.28.3](https://hg.mozilla.org/projects/nss/file/325b4d4c8f81) and [NSPR 4.13.1](https://hg.mozilla.org/projects/nspr/file/624c3bc4ed4c) with VS2019 + Windows Kit 10 tools and libs, Java 8. I have installed DLL files (jss4.dll, libplc4.dll, libnspr4.dll, libplds4.dll) in Mozilla Firefox directory and jss4.jar in jre_path/lib/ext directory. Without success after all those efforts ... :(

I really need help.

Any idea?
(I cannot switch applet to another thing - I do not have this choice)

Comment: *"Any idea?"* Switch to another thing. See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/moving-to-a-plugin-free-web).
*"(I cannot switch applet to another thing - I do not have this choice)"* I feel for you. Especially since most developers that (used to) help with applets could not be bothered trying, these days.

Comment: I think it could be the best thing to do ... While waiting for a hypothetical solution, I have disabled mutual authentication only on pages where the applet is mandatory. Now, it works on Firefox. We will plan to remove Java applet (should have been done a long time ago).

Comment: All the best with the bounty. *"We will plan to remove Java applet"* Wise move. Even if the applet is fixed, it'll be another 6 months to a year before a further maintenance issue pops up, and within a year or two you'll have spent more time fixing the applet than developing an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if the problem is with your webserver providing the https.

A random google throws up the [Mozilla Security Blog](https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2017/02/23/the-end-of-sha-1-on-the-public-web/). SHA-1 is disabled by default in the version of Firefox that you are using (52). MD5 is a worse hashing algorithm that SHA-1.

So presumably you should at least update the webserver. If you are desperate to keep using software that should have been binned, then I guess you there may still be a configuration option in Firefox, or use version 51, but I really wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but I tried with Firefox 51.0.1 without success. I also tried to change the configuration key `security.pki.sha1_enforcement_level` to 0, 1 or 2 (instead of 3 by default) on Firefox 52.4.1 ESR ... Doesn't work either.